# Android jetpack biometric DeviceCredentialHandlerActivity exported=true really needed?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-biometric-prompt

I implemented the new biometric lib using setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true) as shown in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth)

In this lib there is an activity being used "DeviceCredentialHandlerActivity", this activity has **exported=true** in the manifest, why is this/is this really needed? As many should know exporting activities should be avoided if possible for security reassons. I have overridden the property with:

```
<activity android:name="androidx.biometric.DeviceCredentialHandlerActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:replace="android:exported">
        </activity>
```

and authentication with fingerprint/password is still working on Android 29 AND below.

Comment: did you find this created no problems on older devices?

Answer (score 1):

The [commit message](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/866e91d3926e3ab80e99237478ecdb139dc6a536) for this change:

> **Export biometric DeviceCredentialHandlerActivity**
>
> Ensures that DeviceCredentialHandlerActivity is exported so that other
> activities can launch it through BiometricPrompt without having to
> explicitly add it to the corresponding app's manifest.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm still not sure in what specific case this would be needed, do you understand it?